# Adding a scroll bar to a label

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a label on a userForm and the data within it is in list form.  The data is longer than the label.  Without expanding the label, is there a way to add a scroll bar to it?  Or is there another option?  Basically I want a box that does not have a scroll bar unless the list is longer than the box, then there's a scroll bar.

Using Excel vba userForm

Comment: Don't use a label, use the correct control instead.  (Probably a text box)  This is a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @clintp: Well, I tried creating a text box and copying the code for the label and just replacing the name and I get an error that says "Method or data member not found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can used a textbox styled to look like a label.  Set it to multiline with scrollbars set to vertical.  Scrollbars will only show up if the content exceeds the size.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have scroll bar for label, instead a textbox can be used.
Set textbox with "Enabled" and "Locked" properties as"true". User will then have a scrollable and noneditable view

For vertical scrolling, set "WordWrap" and "MultiLine" to True

- Now you could view the scroll bar on tapping the textbox. If you want the scroll bar to be visible by default, on the form load event we need to set the focus of textbox as below:

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  errorText.SetFocus
  End Sub