# Method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I get this error when I run my code.  This is a continuation from this post:
[Adding a scroll bar to a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667403/adding-a-scroll-bar-to-a-label)

I first created a userForm that had labels that retrieved information from a worksheet.  I wanted a scroll bar added so that I could view the list in the label if it was longer than the label.  I was told to try a text box.  I took this line from my code:

```
reportDate.Caption = reportDate.Caption & Sheets("DATA2").Range("P" & rowNum).Text & vbCrLf
```

and copied it and just added a number 1 after it for the text box so the code for the text box is:

```
reportDate1.Caption = reportDate1.Caption & Sheets("DATA2").Range("P" & rowNum).Text & vbCrLf
```

It is this line where there is an error (the title of the post).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you create a text box object called `reportDate1` or just copy the code?

If there is no object called `reportDate1` and no variable `Dim`ed and no `Option Explicit` statement at the top of the module then `reportDate1` will be a variant, which has no Caption Method or property

Something starnge in the neighbourhood...  below is a screen shot of a simple test case in developement mode and run mode.  Text is an arbitary string, no line breaks.  Version/OS may be an issue?  I used Windows Excel 2010.

[image]

Comment: @chris neilsen: Yes, I have a text box called reportDate1.

Comment: @chris neilsen: Actually now it's just all jambed together to fill the whole text box.  Not in list form.

Comment: There is also a .ScrollBars property, you can choose Horizontal, Vertical, Both, none

Comment: @chris neilsen:  I trid that with no luck.  I added an image above of what the text box looks like.

Comment: Hmmm... added screen shot to my answer, see if you can spot any differences

Answer (score 0):

And did you create an object named reportDate1 on your form?